# I can't update the data about an item in the database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I'm new to android development, please help. I have a RecyclerView – it has a list of items opposite each of which there is an opportunity to add it to favorites.

When clicking on the ImageButton, the updateAddToFavourite method is called, which should update the data on the record in the database (change the value in the column from 0 to 1), but when I launch the application and click on the favorites button, I get an error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.foodmap, PID: 16170
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property db has not been initialized

What am I doing wrong?

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.foodmap

import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.foodmap.DatabaseHelper
import com.example.foodmap.DatabaseHelper.columnProducts_id
import com.example.foodmap.DatabaseHelper.columnSafetyIndicator
import com.example.foodmap.DatabaseHelper.tableProducts
import com.example.foodmap.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeader
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileDrawerItem
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnItemClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var databaseHelper: DatabaseHelper
    lateinit var db: SQLiteDatabase
    private lateinit var productCursor: Cursor
    private lateinit var fodmapCursor: Cursor
    private lateinit var productAdapter: ProductAdapter
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mDrawer: Drawer
    private lateinit var mHeader: AccountHeader
    private lateinit var mToolbar: Toolbar
    private val TAG = "MainActivity" // костыль чтобы вызвать метод из MainActivity

    private fun initial() {
        recyclerView = binding.rvProducts
        productAdapter = ProductAdapter(myProducts(), this)
        recyclerView.adapter = productAdapter
        mToolbar = binding.mainToolbar
    }

    private fun initFunc() {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
        createHeader()
        createDrawer()
    }

    private fun createDrawer() {
        mDrawer =
            DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(mToolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withSelectedItem(-1)
                .withAccountHeader(mHeader)
                .addDrawerItems(
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Профиль пользователя")
                        .withSelectable(false),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Мой дневник")
                        .withSelectable(false),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Мои продукты")
                        .withSelectable(false),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(4)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Мои рецепты")
                        .withSelectable(false),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(5)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Выход")
                        .withSelectable(false)
                ).withOnDrawerItemClickListener(object : Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener {
                    override fun onItemClick(
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        drawerItem: IDrawerItem<*>
                    ): Boolean {
                        val newIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SelectedProducts::class.java)

                        when (position) {
                            3 -> startActivity(newIntent)
                        }
                        return false
                    }
                }).build()
    }

    private fun createHeader() {
        mHeader = AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
            .addProfiles(
                ProfileDrawerItem()
                    .withName("Денис Белозёров")
                    .withIcon(R.drawable._avatar180)
                    .withEmail("denis.belozerov@edu.hse.ru")
            )
            .build()
    }

    private fun myProducts(): ArrayList<ProductModel> {
        val productList = ArrayList<ProductModel>()
        val count: Int = productCursor.count

        var i = 0
        while (i < count) {
            var colorSafety = getColor(R.color.green) // храним цвет каждого продукта

            productCursor.moveToPosition(i)
            val nameProduct: String =
                productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnProductsName))
            val categoryProduct: String =
                productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnCategoryName))
            val safetyIndicator: String =
                productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnSafetyIndicator))

            when (safetyIndicator) {
                "Безопасен" -> colorSafety = getColor(R.color.green)
                "Небезопасен" -> colorSafety = getColor(R.color.red)
                "Умеренно безопасен" -> colorSafety = getColor(R.color.yellow)
            }

            productList.add(ProductModel(nameProduct, categoryProduct, colorSafety))
            i++
        }
        return productList
    }

    private fun createAlertDialog(
        title: String,
        olygos: String,
        fructose: String,
        polyols: String,
        lactose: String,
        weight: String
    ) {
        val productDialogView =
            LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog_info_products_1, null)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(productDialogView).setTitle(title)

        val textViewWeight: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Product_weight_1_1_1)
        val textViewOlygos: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Olygos_1_1_2)
        val textViewFructose: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Fructose_1_1_3)
        val textViewPolyols: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Polyols_1_1_4)
        val textViewLactose: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Lactose_1_1_5)

        textViewWeight.setText(weight + " гр")
        textViewOlygos.setText(olygos)
        textViewFructose.setText(fructose)
        textViewPolyols.setText(polyols)
        textViewLactose.setText(lactose)

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
        }
        builder.show()
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(product: ProductModel) {
        val queryFodmap =
            "SELECT Продукты._id, Продукты.[Название продукта], Продукты.[Наличие глютена], FODMAP.[Единицы измерения гр], FODMAP.[Наличие Olygos (олигосахариды)], FODMAP.[Наличие Fructose (фруктоза)], FODMAP.[Наличие Polyols (полиолы)], FODMAP.[Наличие Lactose (лактоза)] FROM Продукты INNER JOIN FODMAP ON Продукты.[Название продукта] = FODMAP.[Название продукта] WHERE Продукты.[Название продукта] = \"${product.product}\""
        fodmapCursor = db.rawQuery(queryFodmap, null)
        fodmapCursor.moveToFirst()
        val itemOlygos =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapOlygos)) // извлекаем характеристики продукта и передаем в AlertDialog
        val itemFructose =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapFructose))
        val itemPolyols =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapPolyols))
        val itemLactose =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapLactose))
        val itemWeight =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapUnit))
        createAlertDialog(
            "${product.product}",
            itemOlygos,
            itemFructose,
            itemPolyols,
            itemLactose,
            itemWeight
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(applicationContext)
        databaseHelper.create_db()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        db = databaseHelper.open()

        val queryProducts =
            "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.tableProducts + " INNER JOIN " + DatabaseHelper.tableCategory + " ON " + "Продукты.[Категория продукта] = Категория.[Код категории]"
        val queryFodmap =
            "SELECT Продукты._id, Продукты.[Название продукта], Продукты.[Наличие глютена], FODMAP.[Единицы измерения гр], FODMAP.[Наличие Olygos (олигосахариды)], FODMAP.[Наличие Fructose (фруктоза)], FODMAP.[Наличие Polyols (полиолы)], FODMAP.[Наличие Lactose (лактоза)]\n" +
                    "FROM Продукты INNER JOIN FODMAP ON Продукты.[Название продукта] = FODMAP.[Название продукта]"

        productCursor = db.rawQuery(queryProducts, null)
        fodmapCursor = db.rawQuery(queryFodmap, null)

        initial()
        initFunc()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        db.close()
        productCursor.close()
    }

    companion object {
        val instance = MainActivity()
    }

    fun updateAddToFavourite(position: Int) {
        db.execSQL("UPDATE ${DatabaseHelper.tableProducts} SET ${DatabaseHelper.columnSafetyIndicator} = 1 WHERE ${DatabaseHelper.columnProducts_id} == $position")
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.foodmap;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME = "fodmap.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1;
    static final String tableProducts = "Продукты";
    static final String columnProducts_id = "_id";
    static final String columnProductsName = "Название продукта";
    static final String columnProductsCode = "Код продукта";
    static final String columnProductsCategory = "Категория продукта";
    static final String columnProductsGluten = "Наличие глютена";
    static final String columnProductsProtein = "Содержание белков (на 100 гр)";
    static final String columnProductsFats = "Содержание жиров (на 100 гр)";
    static final String columnProductsCarb = "Содержание углеводов (на 100 гр)";
    static final String columnSafetyIndicator = "Индикатор безопасности";

    static final String tableCategory = "Категория";
    static final String columnCategoryCode = "Код категории";
    static final String columnCategoryName = "Название категории";

    static final String tableFODMAP = "FODMAP";
    static final String columnFodmapProducts = "Название продукта";
    static final String columnFodmapUnit = "Единицы измерения гр";
    static final String columnFodmapOlygos = "Наличие Olygos (олигосахариды)";
    static final String columnFodmapFructose = "Наличие Fructose (фруктоза)";
    static final String columnFodmapPolyols = "Наличие Polyols (полиолы)";
    static final String columnFodmapLactose = "Наличие Lactose (лактоза)";

    private Context myContext;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) { }

    void create_db(){

        File file = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            //получаем локальную бд как поток
            try(InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Открываем пустую бд
                OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH)) {

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                myOutput.flush();
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

ProductAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.foodmap
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.foodmap.databinding.ItemProductsLayoutBinding

class MyHolder(val binding: ItemProductsLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    val name_product = binding.nameProduct
    val name_category = binding.categoryProduct
    val safety_indicator: ImageView = binding.safetyIndicator
    val add_to_favorite: ImageButton = binding.addToFavorite
    var buttonOn: Boolean = false

    fun bind(product: ProductModel, clickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
        name_product.text = product.product
        name_category.text = product.category
        safety_indicator.setColorFilter(product.safetyIndicator)

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.onItemClicked(product)
        }
    }
}

class ProductAdapter(
    private var products: ArrayList<ProductModel>,
    val itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_products_layout, parent, false)
        return MyHolder(ItemProductsLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(myHolder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentPosition = products.get(position)
        myHolder.bind(currentPosition, itemClickListener)

        myHolder.binding.addToFavorite.setOnClickListener {
            if (!myHolder.buttonOn) {
                myHolder.buttonOn = true
                myHolder.add_to_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24)
                val getMainActivity = MainActivity.instance
                getMainActivity.updateAddToFavourite(position)

            } else {
                myHolder.buttonOn = false
                myHolder.add_to_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_border_24)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return products.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setList(list: ArrayList<ProductModel>) {
        products = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClicked(product: ProductModel)
}
```

item_products_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_product"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_product"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_product"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Product"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_product"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_product"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Category"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/safety_indicator"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_to_favorite"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@color/red"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_to_favorite"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_favorite_border_24"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I can't understand why there was an error in initializing the database, so I tried to add initialization to the OnStart method, but this did not lead to changes.

UPD: Full text of the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.foodmap, PID: 20133
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property db has not been initialized
> at com.example.foodmap.MainActivity.getDb(MainActivity.kt:30)
> at com.example.foodmap.MainActivity.updateAddToFavourite(MainActivity.kt:230)
> at com.example.foodmap.ProductAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda$0(ProductAdapter.kt:49)
> at com.example.foodmap.ProductAdapter.$r8$lambda$2q2XJ3l7i7sA7ZsUTOGFIU09fiQ(Unknown Source:0)
> at com.example.foodmap.ProductAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7542)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7519)
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29476)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7918)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

Comment: `val instance = MainActivity()` don't do this.  It's a memory leak in the best case, but you can't create `Activity` instances yourself.